# How to properly interpret git subtrees in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-subtree

I am able to add subtrees to my visual studio project via command line, but when I do it requires me to add a prefix. When I do this it adds a sub directory in the root directory. When I add the subtree's projects to my solution, all the references are not available because the packages are in the root directory/packages. If I update the paths, the paths are now messed up in the original subtree repo. How do you properly set up two projects with one being reference via subtrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way that I can maintain the subtree is to:

1. Move the subtree into the housing solution with the subdirectory
2. Fix References within each subtree project

   a. Unload each subtree project

   b. Edit each .csproj file
   enter code here

   c. Reroute all the ..\packages to ..\ ..\packages with each .csproj files after

   d. Reload Projects
3. Maintain the Subtree repo within the Holding Solutions what used the shared repo

Let me know if this is the only solution. Cause it screws up my main subtree's repo packages so I can only test it from within the shared solutions or i have to reroute the packages path each time

Comment: That seems more detailed than my answer. +1

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for now, but if you have a better solution please post it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, for now.

`git subtree` support is still pending, as shown in [this suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-for-git-subtrees-from-visual-stu/1544686):

> support for git subtrees from visual studio gui

The only way to use git subtrees presently is from the command line, and as you have seen, they are not properly interpreted from the VS project.
If you want to have this feature implemented in Visual Studio there is only one way - you have to vote up for the suggestion.

Comment: I know it's possible as we had a project at my last job that was using subtrees.

Comment: @Demodave Did you try this setup in command-line first (adding the second project as subtree, in command line), then importing the resulting project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, that is what exactly is described in my description. I know how to add the subtree, I just don't know how to get the visual studio to work being all the projects are in a sub directory.